# nested function change variable in an outside function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, python-nonlocal

```
def some_func(a): 
    def access_a():
        print(a)
    access_a()
```

outputs the value of `a`. However, if I want to change `a` in the nested function like this:

```
def some_func(a): 
    def change_a():
        a += 1
        print(a)
    change_a()
```

it raises `UnboundLocalError` exception.

I know `a` is a nonlocal variable, but why can I access it without declaring `nonlocal a`?

Comment: Have you tried `global a` in the functions?

Comment: This is the same thing as with `global`: you can access a global variable, but trying to modify it without `global var` will fail.

Comment: Regardless of any ways to work around this, reaching out like this and causing arbitrary side-effects is not good programming practice.

Comment: ...so you shouldn't be doing it in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python scoping rules 101:

1. a name bound in a function body is considered `local` unless explicitely declared `global` (Python 2.x and 3.x) or `nonlocal` (Python 3.x only). This holds true whereever the assignment happens in the function's body. Trying to read a local variable before it's bound is of course an error.
2. if a name is read but not bound in a function's body, it will be looked up in enclosing scopes (outer function(s) if any then global scope). NB: functions arguments are de facto local names so they will never be looked up in enclosing scopes.

Note that `a += 1` is mainly a shortcut for `a = a + 1`, so in your example `a` is local (bound in the function's body and not explicitely declared global or nonlocal), but you  try to read it (the rhs of `a = a+1`) before it's bound.

In Python 3 you can solve this with a `nonlocal` statement:

```
>>> def outer(a):
...    def change():
...       nonlocal a
...       a += 1
...    print("before : {}".format(a))
...    change()
...    print ("after : {}".format(a))
... 
>>> outer(42)
before : 42
after : 43
```

Python 2 doesn't have `nonlocal` so the canonical hack is to wrap the variable in a mutable container (typically a `list` but any mutable object would do):

```
>>> def outer(a):
...     _a = [a]
...     def change():
...         _a[0] += 1
...     print("before : {}".format(_a[0]))
...     change()
...     print ("after : {}".format(_a[0]))
... 
>>> outer(42)
before : 42
after : 43
```

which is quite ugly to say the least.

Now while closures are quite handy, they are mostly the functional counterpart of objects : a way to share state between a set of functions while preserving encapsulation of this state, so if you find you have a need for a `nonlocal` variable perhaps a proper class might be a cleaner solution (though possibly not for your example that doesn't return the inner function but only uses it internally).

Answer (score 1):

i have two solutions for you:

```
#first one:
# try with list, compound data types dict/list
def some_func(a): 
    def change_a():
        a[0] += 1
        print(a[0])
    change_a()
some_func([1])
>>> 2


#second one
#reference pointer 
from ctypes import *
def some_func_ctypes(a):
    def change_a():
      a[0] += 1
      print a.contents, a[0]
    change_a()

i = c_int(1)
pi = pointer(i)
some_func_ctypes(pi)

>>> c_int(2) 2
```

Comment: What the OP was asking was why he could _read_ a nonlocal variable but not _rebind_ it...

Comment: @bruno, dude you did a great explanation/answer, thx. should i explain it again? i guess its not more needed but a other solution would be great for the future readers...

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `+=` operator, there is an assignment of a new value to `a`. This turns a to a local in the eyes of the interpreter.